# quasar: How to pass custom parameters to q-select filter

Tags: function, select, filter, quasar

q-select has the method @filter with 3 options (val, update, abort).
I need to pass extra parameters to the function.

The passed update() function as an argument is critical for the select to display available options.

And trying to get any access to the data in a table is not possible.

```
<q-select label="Birth City:" 
           option-value="Id" 
           option-label="availableOptionsKey"
           map-options
           v-model="props.row.value" 
           :options="props.row.availableOptions"
           @filter="customFn">
</q-select>
```

When passing arguments, the update() function normally passed to @filter is not available.

```
<q-select label="Birth City:" 
           option-value="Id" 
           option-label="availableOptionsKey"
           map-options
           v-model="props.row.value" 
           :options="props.row.availableOptions"
           @filter="customFn(props.row)">
</q-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is formatted for documentation purposes and originally from a different forum.

The solution is:

```
<q-select label="Birth City:" 
           option-value="Id" 
           option-label="availableOptionsKey"
           map-options
           v-model="props.row.value" 
           :options="props.row.availableOptions"
           @filter="(val, update, abort) => { customFn(val, update, abort, props.row) }">
</q-select>
```

...

```
customFn(val, update,abortFn,row){
            update(() => {
                if (val === '') {//reset|show original
                    row.availableOptions =  this['SomeArrayWithAllOriginalOptions'];
                }else{
                    row.availableOptions =  this['SomeArrayWithAllOriginalOptions'];.filter(v => v.availableOptionsKey.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1)
                } 
            })
        },
```